# Extracting Data between two characters with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I do not have access to write to a database, queries are limited to retrieval only. CTEs are not allowed. Cannot write functions. (Here's a document of what I'm limited to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5)

Here's an example of a string I'm working with, I'm looking to extract the email address, where I consistently know that the email will begin at the fourth |, and end at the fifth |.

```
D||John Smith|EML|test@gmail.com|Y|2014/01/03 17:14:01.000000|
```

This is what I tried so far, it's not able to return any email addresses for me

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('|',AllData) > 0 
           THEN SUBSTRING(AllData, CHARINDEX('|', AllData, 22) + 1, ABS((CHARINDEX('|', AllData, CHARINDEX('@', AllData))) - (CHARINDEX('|', AllData, 22) + 1)))
           ELSE 'NotWorking'
    END AS email
FROM
    [test_file]
```

Comment: You might do better looking in the Land of [Salesforce.SE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/), e.g. searching for [`SQL split`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=sql+split).

Comment: No success in Salesforce world, was hoping to look to this one to see if I could get advice

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `string_split()`:

```
select s.value
from test_file tf cross apply
     string_split(alldata, '|') s
where s.value like '%@%.%';
```

This doesn't extract the fourth value.  It extracts any value that looks like an email -- but it is pretty simple code that should work.

Comment: String_Split is not a function I can use unfortunately